# File not found on File.Exists with spaces in path

Tags: c#, path

If my executable is running from a path with no spaces, this

```
if(!File.Exists(@"\program.exe"))
    MessageBox.Show("File not found");
```

doesn't fire. But, if the program executes from a path with spaces, like `C:\Program Files\etc\` I get a file not found. My executable application and `program.exe` lies in the same folder.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/P3CbO.png....works for me

Comment: @RoyiNamir Well, I can't control where my users want to install the application :P

Comment: You should use it like 
!File.Exists(@"C:\Program Files\etc\program.exe")

Comment: So remove the back-slash.....**Also** if you install a program  - you should read the installation directory through registry.

Comment: @royinamir how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the execution directory path and append it to your `exe` file name

```
string DirPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
if(!File.Exists(DirPath + @"\program.exe"))
    MessageBox.Show("File not found");
```

Answer (score 4):

Though it may *seem* like the path has something to do with it, it's the Working Directory. Try this code:

```
var path = Path.Combine(
    Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
        "program.exe");
if (!File.Exists(path))
```

The path in which is it launched wouldn't cause that code to fail. However, when the working directory isn't what's expected; that will.

Furthermore, *never assume* that you're in a specific directory. Always provide a fully qualified path. Objects like the `SaveFileDialog` and `OpenFileDialog` can change the working directory on you at runtime.

Comment: This path results in `C:\app\bin\Release\MyApplication.exe\program.exe"`, so that wont work

Comment: @Wilhelmsen, where where in the world is this "program.exe"?

Comment: In the same folder as my executable. It is a program that my application has to run in the background from time to time.

Comment: @Wilhelmsen, of course. The `Location` property returns the executable name with it. I gotcha.

Answer (score 0):

To check the existence of your file in the "current directory", you have not to put the "\" character. So:

```
if(!File.Exists("program.exe"))
    MessageBox.Show("File not found");
```

[Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/file-exists) a little explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply remove `"\"` from the argument of the method `File.Exists(@"program.exe")`, and check the current working directory by [GetCurremtDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to be sure that relative path you are passing (that *is* relative path) constructs correct full path to executable.

Answer (score 0):

```
File.Exist(@"\program.exe")
```

will check for program.exe at the root of the drive, eg c:\program.exe if your program is running from c: